# How to fork new powershell window and pass in functions?

Tags: powershell

I have a menu driven powershell script does some stuff.

The menu switch consists of..

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateSet('Interactive', 'Scheduler')]
    [string]$Operation = "Interactive"
)

function mytest {
    Write-Host "this is a test"
}}

Switch ($Operation)
{
    'Interactive' { . (Join-Path $ScriptPath main.ps1) }
    'Scheduler' { . (Join-Path $ScriptPath scheduler.ps1) }
    'Shell' { . (Join-Path $ScriptPath shell.ps1) }
}
```

There are a bunch of functions that I have defined in this script and I would like to be able to call the script with `"myscript.ps1 -Operation Shell"` that forks a new powershell console where I can manually type in commands and also have access to the defined functions that were set during the execution of the main script.

This would be no different than running powershell console manually in Windows, except called via a script that sets a bunch of functions and parameters.

Comment: I would just put the functions in my profile.

Comment: I would usually end up doing just that, however for this particular purpose I need to be able to call a script that has an option to drop into console and be aware of all the functions that were set during the execution. Is this possible?

Comment: If you put the functions in the AllUsersAllHosts profile then they should be available no matter what.

Comment: I don't want these functions available for every session, this is for a special case only when running a particular script. Putting it in AllUsersAllHosts will be available all the time on the system no?

Comment: `ForEach ($def in (Get-ChildItem -Path Function:)) { }`

Comment: An easier way, however, would be `Export-PSSession`